# What does 'lie' mean in this quote of Sydney Smith?

Tags: meaning, british-english

Could someone please explain the meaning of the word 'lie' in this sentence?

> "Webster was a living lie, because no man on earth could be as great as he looked."

Thanks

Comment: It's a ***figurative*** usage. Just as a ***statement*** is a "lie" if what you understand it to mean is in fact "untrue", Smith is saying that ***Webster*** is a (metaphorical) lie because he seems to be unbelievably "great" (greater than any man could *possibly* be), so ***his appearance must be deceptive***.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lie is a statement that isn't true. In this sentence the description ("not true") is applied to the apparent shape of Webster's life. Webster looks great but can't be that great because no man on earth could be.

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live%20a%20lie

> Definition of live a lie
>
> : to live in a false or deceptive way : to live in a way that does not
> show who one truly is or what one's feelings truly are
>
> Their friends
> thought that they had a happy marriage, but they were living a lie.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an exaggeration, a display of affection towards an exceptionally handsome (in Sydney's opinion) man.

A lie is [a statement intended to deceive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lie#Noun_2). She felt she was deceived, tricked by his good-looking appearance which she couldn't comprehend  - no man on earth could be as great as he looked.

It's closely related to an idiom [live a lie](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/live-a-lie)

> My mother never told my father the truth about me. We've been **living a lie** all this time.

which usually (but not here) carries a negative connotation.